# CSS transition not working in Styled Component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make the transition slowly (500ms) scale the Brandsdiv when `props.pop` changes. `pop` will equal `true` or `false`. Currently, `transform: ${props => (props.pop ? "scale(1.2)" : "scale(1)")};` works fine and scales the div when `pop = true` but the transition is not working - the scaling abruptly changes.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const LogoImg = styled.img`
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
`

export default function FeaturedManufacturerLink(props) {
  const {
    brandPagePath, 
    logo, 
    pop
  } = props

  const Brandsdiv = styled.div`
    transition: transform 500ms;
    display: flex;
    width: 116px;
    height: 85px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 25px 35px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    transform: ${props => (props.pop ? "scale(1.2)" : "scale(1)")};
  `
  return (
    <Brandsdiv pop={pop}>
      <a href={brandPagePath}>
        <LogoImg src={logo} />
      </a>
    </Brandsdiv>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved `const Brandsdiv`. The prop change `pop` was causing the component to rerender.